# Why session number changes in custom report depending if I order by session or visit?

Tags: session, google-analytics

I run a custom report filter on my website by locale ( /br, from Brazil, in the url). In March, there was a change in the layout of the website, and I ran a custom report with the above filter and I found that the number of session changes dependening on what I order the number for.

To give an example:
I ran a custom report, with the number of sessions and users as metrics, and Date as dimension, and a filter including pages with a regex "/br", from 2015-03-01 to 2015-03-31.

Ordering the results by sessions, GA reports 4.651 on 20130312, but if I order by users, GA reports 4.657 for the same day!
This change of numbers also happens if I decide to show not only ten results per page, but 50. 
Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your website has a lot of visits per month and reports are influenced by sampling.

I tried to use long period(March 2015) for one of websites - and get similar situation: sessions and users for same date/hour are changed depending on sort type(users vs. sessions).

But when I tried to analyse short period(2 days), sessions and users **were not changed** depending on sort type.

So I think, this happens because of sampling in your case.

Comment: I'll take a look at this to see if that's the reason. If so, I'll mark this as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, hope it will helpful for you